# Can I configure latexmk to fail on undefined references/citations?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, latexmk

I would like to have latexmk to fail on undefined references/citations. My initial thoughts were to accomplish this by checking the final output for "Reference ... undefined" warnings and exiting with non-zero status.

Comment: I think that although your question is well defined you should nonetheless give a MWE that does not exit with the non-zero status.

Comment: I guess part of the problem is that latexmk is designed to be run repeatedly until the references and citations are all resolved.  So which run do you want your "fail" to happen? 1st run, 2nd run, 3rd run...  Maybe a different tool would be a better choice.

Comment: Arara sounds like what you might use for this https://ctan.org/pkg/arara?lang=en

Comment: This is about [tag:bibliographies] and not about [tag:cross-referencing]!

Comment: @AFeldman Not really. Solutions might look different for documents with `thebibliography`, `\bibliographystyle{}` and `\usepackage{biblatex}` and the last also has the choice of backend, which again affects what information might be available from the console output. Of course, you no doubt could write a script to detect which situation applies, but, if so, that too should be made clear in the question.

Comment: Is this about cross-references *and* citations or only citations? Or cross-references to or from citations? Or all of the above?

Comment: I understand the question to be about what happens after latexmk has finished all its runs and there remain undefined citations or cross references.  At present latexmk copies the behavior of latex and exits with zero return code, i.e., this condition isn't treated as an error.  But latexmk does examine the log file for undefined references and citations, to display a list at the end of the run. It would need some (fairly easy) reprogramming to change latexmk's return code.  That would be useful is latexmk is invoked as part of a bigger process.

Comment: Thank you, @JohnCollins, and thank you for maintaining latexmk in the first place! Indeed, I am calling latexmk from a build system, and your proposal is exactly what I was looking for.  Not knowing any perl, I took a look at the source code, and came up with (this gist)[https://gist.github.com/jonatanolofsson/08efb9f6c0983e61a972d70da7a049e2] (there's a diff at the far bottom), though I far too unexperienced to see if this is a good approach..?

Comment: especially with regards to the iterative nature of latex compilation

Comment: @templar Thanks for the code. However, the test converting reference and citation warnings to an error occurs too early, after a compilation.  So it prevents latexmk from doing the repeated compilations needed to resolve references and citations.  I'm working on a corrected version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just added this possibility to `latexmk`.  A new version 4.55a is now available for testing from http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html  For details, see the documentation for the option `-Werror` and for the configuration variable `$warnings_as_errors`.  When the option `-Werror` is used, warnings about undefined references or citations or multiply defined references result in a non-zero status code (indicating an error) being returned by `latexmk` to the operating system. The warnings are those on the **last** run of `(pdf)latex`, when for an error-free document all references and citations should have become defined.

In addition, I've given a way for getting a visual indicator in preview-continuous mode for these same warnings about references and citations.  See the documentation for the variables `$compiling_cmd`, `$failure_cmd`, `$warning_cmd`, and `$success_cmd`.  I find this addition very useful.